# How to get digits = ["12", "145", " 45", "12.4", "45,14", "15 645"] numbers

Tags: python

```
def fix(i):
   return i.replace(",",".") and i.replace(" ","") and float(i)
```

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '45,14'
```

Comment: `i.replace` does not update the variable `i`, it returns a new value.

Answer (score 1):

Your question in very vague. But I will give it a go for you.

```
["12", "145", "45", "12.4", "45,14", "15 645"]
```

1. 

Assuming you just want the list to be the digits only but still a string

```
digits = ["12", "145", "45", "12.4", "45,14", "15 645"]
new_digits = [dgt.replace(",","").replace(".","").replace(" ","") for dgt in digits]
print(new_digits)
```

output

```
["12", "145", "45", "124", "4514", "15645"]
```

2. 

If you want them as a integer then wrap it with an int().

```
digits = ["12", "145", "45", "12.4", "45,14", "15 645"]
new_digits = [int(dgt.replace(",","").replace(".","").replace(" ","")) for dgt in digits]
print(new_digits)
```

output

```
[12, 145, 45, 124, 4514, 15645]
```

3. 

If you want them all in one string then you could do the following.

```
digits = ["12", "145", "45", "12.4", "45,14", "15 645"]
out_str = "" 

for number in digits:
    for single_number in number:
        if not single_number in [",","."," "]:
            out_str += single_number
print(out_str)
```

output

```
1214545124451415645
```

4. 

or if you want to return floats for each then.

```
digits = ["12", "145", "45", "12.4", "45,14", "15 645"]
new_digits = [float(dgt.replace(",",".").replace(" ",".")) for dgt in digits]
print(new_digits)
```

output

```
[12.0, 145.0, 45.0, 12.4, 45.14, 15.645]
```